# How to add custom sort order to a taxonomy field list?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to sort the list of content according to the weight order given to taxonomy term.

**Terminology used:**

`content type`    : contact-person-details

`taxonomy`        : company vocabulary which has list of company names like company A, company B, ...

`session company` : every user has a company which is stored in session, users have similar company names too.

**how it works now:** Imagine I am from "company A" stored in my session. Based on my company, content in a view is getting shown (company A is the taxonomy term used for filtering).
Views are used to filter the content type contact-person-details. Varies from company to company which was tagged to content, based on user session company.

**What I am trying to achieve?** Image below helps in understanding the visual concept. Imagine list (Test one, Test sort, ...) shown are the company vocabulary lists, just like (company A, company B, ...) I want an additional field or textbox just to the side of each term showing to add `weight`. This weight should be available in the view so that I'm able to making sorting based on the weight allocated for each content.

[image]

I would like to know is there a existing possibility to weight the taxonomy list in field.

If it is still complex to understand I will try to edit my explanation.

Comment: Can you tag this with the Drupal version, please?

Comment: opps, tagged now.

Answer (score 0):

The [Taxonomy Term Reference Sortable Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_sortable) module appears to meet your requirement. Once installed, the module will provide a widget that can be selected for a taxonomy term field via its widget type panel. (Admin -> Structure -> Content Types -> My Content Type -> Manage Fields -> My Field -> Widget Type).

If you have a lot of different terms available this may not be a good choice because it displays a full master list of terms from which you select and order those you need. It does not have an option for using autocomplete to build the set.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this seems to be helpful but not meeting my requirement. As I am using a field as entity reference instead of term reference. This works only for term reference. Yet I will have an understanding how to make a custom module to work on my scenario.

Comment: Yes, although the maintainer of the module refused to make it work with entity references it's probably not that big a job to adapt it if you are able to write custom module code.